# How to extract data from 'application/pkcs7-mime' using the email-module in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, email, base64, email-attachments, decoding

## Problem

I am working on a project where we have to classify e-mails. For this project I need to extract ALL text from the e-mails and their attachments.

My problem is that some attachments are of the type "application/pkcs7-mime", and I am not sure how to handle those.

## What I have tried

```
import email, base64

# Opening message
eml_file = '/path/to/file.eml'
message = email.message_from_file(open(eml_file))

# Printing content types
for part in message.walk():
    print(part.get_content_type())

>multipart/mixed
 text/plain
 message/rfc822
 application/pkcs7-mime
```

The part that is giving the problems is "application/pkcs7-mime". Next I try to extract data from the payload.

```
# Ensuring we got the right payload
message.get_payload(1).get_payload(0).get_content_type()
>application/pkcs7-mime

# Getting payload
message.get_payload(1).get_payload(0).get_payload()
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADCABgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggxDhqwSD
EOGmQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBtdWx0aXBhcnQvbWl4ZWQ7IGJvdW5kYXJ5PV8wMDRfRkVGNjMyNEIy
NDFFNDA5MEFBMUQ3RUQ5QUZBQkZFMDdic2Vka187DQogbWljYWxnPXNoYTI1Ng0KDQotLV8wMDRf
RkVGNjMyNEIyNDFFNDA5MEFBMUQ3RUQ5QUZBQkZFMDdic2Vka18NCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogdGV4
dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04DQpDb250ZW50LUlEOiA8Mzg3NTg2Nzk0M0UzNkY0OUEzQjcy
.......
```

It looks like the payload is encoded in base64, so I try to decode it:

```
# Decoding message
message.get_payload(1).get_payload(0).get_payload(decode=True).decode("iso-8859-1")

# Top of output
 á«á¦Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_004_FEF6324B241E4090AA1D7ED9AFABFE07bsedk_;
 micalg=sha256

--_004_FEF6324B241E4090AA1D7ED9AFABFE07bsedk_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-ID: <3875867943E36F49A3B72D0FAEB1DC35@eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6b2ZmaWNlIiB4
bWxuczp3PSJ1cm46c2NoZW1hcy1taWNyb3NvZnQtY29tOm9mZmljZTp3b3JkIiB4bWxuczptPSJo
dHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL29mZmljZS8yMDA0LzEyL29tbWwiIHhtbG5zPSJo

# Bottom of output
0U 0U00, * (&http://crl.oces.trust2408.com/oces.crl0\ Z X¤V0T10 UDK10U
×ÿÑE|g¢¿ºÊ]6¾ãñJfYéÿBû´s²J7ª¡-*¨    Ø p@6¨Ë9Ç¦íæýÕUB9Íõ £àg&7î!Ö®?sÒ
8Wè>º|mIh +|2¨Ü%«O´|%o¬¦¥ð¶oòÝ¿t³ é¾ÏPÒëqûW®ö8|¼èÇçqQL ½þ¹Ù`¶¿*7ÒýsÎKb!ÿ¶?:{¸½Ú\õ{ÕþyÅI
.­éÃÂKèj36q°lD}|RÎàIzÙ/^[j;3¶Ðà+®r$¥!1ß0Û0I0A10 UDK10UªÏÒ¶,`§rÌbèñy5&FJÃ(êí°&¬,ÚêX$á.=ïïæN$®]Þ½yU0+*§ÔÚ´í6azL(!DÏÝ6ÂNê,Ä5FsíXEó§î_»SG]Úüåt Ô¼'âröÓg!ðSÐ,O¶x><s5ÖRv«N¸¡¿<ý>¼VBñ¤f[ÔÏàø7¿ÂûÊ
uidÊUS!ÂÕÜÚæòÜíþµüâeüLü'^[¦/d{«oäp¹ÁNî÷Å½½Oq$Øà-W
DsüèXÀÎ}á¾9ÀÌ¹ÙÎhAÎ ¯P¾ñäK!VIrÏÌ¯Ín,º~¿IÐ{[D¢=ý%Úîckr¿·_³EÙ]¨g0âk:`vÄÖ</È»HBà4%ª]|;~wÐ=·&;êºÕAr«Á¡GÅòØ)wÂd{Ù    BvÞ·3ºàCÔ
```

## Conclusion

Some of the message is decoded correctly, while the rest is a mess. I can, however, not figure out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have fixed the problem by writing handling these files, by removing the junk from the header, and converting them back to messages. This seems to work for now.

```
    if message.get_filename() == "smime.p7m":
        message = email.message_from_bytes(re.sub(r'.*Content-Type:', 'Content-Type:', decoded).encode("iso-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I ended up in the same situation and fixed my problem with the answer from esben-eickhardt. But I was not very happy with cutting away some unknown stuff just to let it work.

## Preparation/Reading

- RFC 8551 - Secure/Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (S/MIME)

  - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551
  - *mime body is put into the mail as CMS*
- RFC 5652 - Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)

  - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652
  - *CMS is encoded with ANS.1 data structure*
- RFC 4792 - Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1)

  - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4792

### Verification with openssl

Extract, base64 decode the p7m file and call openssl

```
openssl asn1parse -in smime.p7m -inform der
```

this should magically return a human readable structure of the CMS. You should see the mail as one of many keys in the CMS.

## Solution

We need a ASN.1 parser to read the CMS data. As second step we extract the inner mail.

### Python

Python package `asn1crypto` is an ASN.1 parser, but also has CMS support. So now we can load the CMS into a python representation.

```
if part.get_content_type() in ['application/pkcs7-mime'] and part.get_param('smime-type') == 'signed-data':
    from asn1crypto import cms
    content_info = cms.ContentInfo.load(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    compressed_data = content_info['content']
    smime = compressed_data['encap_content_info']['content'].native
    smime_message = email.message_from_string(smime)
```

Comment: I agree, I wish there was another solution too! Keep me posted if you find one.

Comment: I though you went with my solution... Does that final "if-sentence" fix the problem?

Comment: For me the last line smime_message = email.message_from_string(smime) had to be changed to message_from_bytes
Other than that: thank you so much for this answer I did not find anything even close as useful as this after hours of google research.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt yes, the 'if-sentence code' fixes your problem without any magic tricks

Comment: @PSC this might be needed for pyhton3.