# How can I check the date of a digital signature of a p7m file?

Tags: python, digital-signature

I need to check the date on which the digital signature was applied on a p7m file.
I searched in Stack Overflow, but without success.

As in the image, I just need to verify the information highlighted.

[image: example]

Comment: Do you try `openssl asn1parse -in smime.p7m -inform der` command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60491617/434255 answer?

Comment: @ont.rif thank you, i'll try